# unique_ptr with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, smart-pointers

I have some fear about using `unique_ptr` with multithreading without `mutex`. I wrote simplified code below, please take a look.  If I check `unique_ptr != nullptr`, is it thread safe?

```
class BigClassCreatedOnce
{
public:
    std::atomic<bool> var;

    // A lot of other stuff
};
```

`BigClassCreatedOnce` class instance will be created only once but I'm not sure is it safe to use it between threads.

```
class MainClass
{
public:
    // m_bigClass used all around the class from the Main Thread

    MainClass()
        : m_bigClass()
        , m_thread()
    {
        m_thread = std::thread([this]() {
            while (1)
            {
                methodToBeCalledFromThread();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            }
        });

        // other stuff here

        m_bigClass.reset(new BigClassCreatedOnce()); // created only once
    }

    void methodToBeCalledFromThread()
    {
        if (!m_bigClass) // As I understand this is not safe
        {
            return;
        }

        if (m_bigClass->var.load()) // As I understand this is safe
        {
            // does something
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<BigClassCreatedOnce> m_bigClass;
    std::thread m_thread;
};
```

I just put it into infinity loop to simplify the sample.

```
int main()
{
    MainClass ms;
    while (1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create the thread after `m_bigClass` has been set?

Comment: If i do so what about comment "access of m_bigClass is not so you could also have a data race there." As I understand it also doesn't fix the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I check `unique_ptr != nullptr`, is it thread safe

No, it is not thread safe.  If you have more than one thread and at least of one of them writes to the shared data then you need synchronization.  If you do not then you have a data race and it is undefined behavior.

```
m_bigClass.reset(new BigClassCreatedOnce()); // created only once
```

and

```
if (!m_bigClass)
```

Can both happen at the same time, so it is a data race.

I would also like to point out that

```
if (m_bigClass->var.load())
```

Is also not thread safe.  `var.load()` is, but the access of `m_bigClass` is not so you could also have a data race there.

Comment: How should it be used correctly? I've never seen someone using atomic to unique_ptr and not sure how code in this situation. Should I simply use mutex or maybe exists some other way?

Comment: @YuriiKomarnytskyi You can use a `mutex`, or you could change to a `std::shared_ptr` that does have overloads of the atomic free functions.  I believe the reasoning for them not existing for a `unique_ptr` is because it is supposed to be unique, and therefore not shared.

Comment: "_supposed to be unique, and therefore not shared_" does not compute ;)

Comment: @curiousguy It does to me.